# Why does this function not return a string that will work ListToArray or ValueList?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I have created a function within a `format.cfc` component that returns a string without any HTML code in it:

```
<cffunction name="RemoveHTML" access="public" returntype="string" output="false" hint="Returns a string without any html">
  <cfargument name="UserString" required="yes">
  <cfset var result = "#REReplaceNoCase(Canonicalize(ARGUMENTS.UserString,false,true),'<[^>]*(?:>|$)', '', 'ALL')#">
  <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

I now want to split the string at each space and convert it into a list. So I tried using ValueList() and ListToArray() but they don't like the value returned from the function.

Using ValueList() I get an error saying:

> Complex constructs are not supported with function ValueList

Or I get this error when using ListToArray:

> Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values

I'm basically just doing this:

```
<!--- ValueList() --->
<title>#ValueList(Application.Format.RemoveHTML(UserString = rsProduct.Title), ' ')#</title>

<!--- ListToArray() --->
<title>#ListToArray(Application.Format.RemoveHTML(UserString = rsProduct.Title), ' ')#</title>
```

If I remove the ListToArray() or ValueList() function then I get back what I expect - a product title string with no HTML in it.

So why is the function not returning a string even though it looks like one? Or am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: Can you post the output of removeHtml function and what final output you are expecting?

Comment: ValueList() is designed to work with query objects so its use on a simple string is inappropriate.  For ListToArray(), try it on a simple string that you type yourself, such as "try this".  See if it converts to an array.

Comment: Cause valueList works with query and listToArray is used to convert list into array.

Comment: If u just want space to replaced by ',' then u have to use replace() to do that

Comment: @DanBracuk I don't think the spaces are being returned as normal spaces from the string. If I perform EncodeForHTMLAttribute() on the string I get things like `Samsung&#x20;Galaxy&#x20;Note&#x20;4`

Comment: If you want to see exactly what is being returned by your function, output it into a textarea or in a `<pre>` block.

Comment: @DanBracuk I have manually typed in and test this `#ListToArray('Samsung Galaxy Note 4', ' ')#` and it refuses it as a complex object type. Buts its just a string that I manually typed in myself.

Comment: @volumeone Are you using `<cfoutput>`? You should use `<cfdump>` as it is a complex object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have noted in the comments, `ValueList` is designed to return a list of values that are contained in a column of a query object. It won't work with a string value.

`ListToArray` converts a list to an array. You can't then output an array in your HTML. So `ListToArray` is working fine, it's when you try to display it in a `cfoutput` that the error occurs.

It's a good idea to use the in-built encoding functions in CF, for example `encodeForHTML`. So you can do something like:

```
<title>#encodeForHTML(Application.Format.RemoveHTML(UserString = rsProduct.Title))#</title>
```

`encodeForHTML`, can accept an optional boolean 2nd argument (which is false by default), to indicate if you want to canonicalize the string. So you may want to do that instead of calling `Canonicalize` in your custom `RemoveHTML` function. After all your function is called `RemoveHTML` not `RemoveHTMLAndCanonicalize` :)

### update

In response to OP's comment.

To get a comma delimited list from your 'space delimited' string, then you can use the `replace` function. Something like:

```
<title>#encodeForHTML(replace(RemoveHTML(rsProduct.Title), " ", ",", "all"))#</title>
```

You can of course, put the `replace` inside your custom function, I'm just demonstrating how it works.

You'll need to be aware, that it'll replace all spaces with a comma, so if you have 2 or more spaces in a row then it'll show `,,` (depending on how many spaces). To get around that you can use a regular expression like so:

```
<title>#encodeForHTML(reReplace(RemoveHTML(rsProduct.Title), " +", ",", "all"))#</title>
```

You can also use `listChangeDelims` intead of `reReplace` as it ignores empty elements.

```
<title>#encodeForHTML(listChangeDelims(RemoveHTML(rsProduct.Title), ",", " "))#</title>
```

Personally I'd go with the regular expression version as it's more powerful, you'll want to wrap it up in a function though to keep the view nice and clean.

Comment: I can do this, but I need to replace the spaces with a comma to make a list

Comment: Ah, OK, well then just use. replace to replace the spaces. Will update the answer.

Comment: That's the problem its not working. I have manually typed in and test this #ListToArray('Samsung Galaxy Note 4', ' ')# and it refuses it as a complex object type. Buts its just a string that I manually typed in myself.

Comment: Have updated the answer - hope that solves your problem and explains what is happening.

Comment: If you do `<cfdump var="#ListToArray('Samsung Galaxy Note 4', ' ')#">` You'll see why it can't just output that inside a `cfoutput` it's an array, not a string.

Comment: Riiiight I've got it now. And this solution pretty much works fine :) Thank you John

Answer (score 1):

I think there are multiple ways to do this, consider below is my text

```
<cfset myText = "Samsung Galaxy Note 4"/>
```

first method by using simple replace function

```
<cfset firstSolution = replace(myText," ",",","all")/>
<cfdump var="#firstSolution#" />
```

Second method by using reReplace method

```
<cfset secondSolution = rEReplace(myText,"\s+",",","all")/>
<cfdump var="#secondSolution#" />
```

If I would be you I would have use second method cause if by any chance I have multiple spaces in my string then instead of getting multiple ',' I will get single ',' given string is used in the title of the page, I would not take any risk have incorrect title.

Comment: What if there are commas in the text?

Comment: This is also good. I use `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s+` personally.